# convert a class to byte array + C#

Tags: c#-3.0

How can I convert a Class to byte array in C#. This is a managed one so the following code is failing

```
int objsize = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(objTimeSeries3D);
byte[] arr = new byte[objsize];
IntPtr buff = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.AllocHGlobal(objsize);
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.StructureToPtr(objTimeSeries3D, buff, true);
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(buff, arr, 0, objsize);
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FreeHGlobal(buff);
```

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need to convert a class to a byte array? If we know the problem you are trying to solve, we may have a _better_ way of doing things.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use [`BinaryFormatter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter.aspx). Note that your class must be [`[Serializable]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serializableattribute.aspx) for this to work.

```
private byte[] ToByteArray(object source)
{
    var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        formatter.Serialize(stream, source);                
        return stream.ToArray();
    }
}
```