# How to convert from a custom type to HttpPostedFileBase

Tags: c#, byte, httppostedfilebase

I have a custom object from one of the classes in my project. So for example object `abc` from type `MyCustomClass`
I need to call a method in my program that's been written before. This method takes a `HttpPostedFileBase` parameter and goes and saves it on Server. 
**So my question is** how can I convert my `object` to be able to pass it to `HttpPostedFileBase` so it can do its job from that point on.

This is what I search and found so far: 
[how to convert a byte[] to HttpPostedFileBase using c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39094997/how-to-convert-a-byte-to-httppostedfilebase-using-c-sharp)

Comment: Can you pass them separately instead of mixing them together?

Comment: @Xiaosu ? Pass them seperately? I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Given what you found, have you attempted to convert a `MyCustomClass` instance to a `byte[]`?

Answer (score 1):

If the method is expecting an `HttpPostedFileBase` you will need to make your `MyCustomClass` to inherit from `HttpPostedFileBase` or just create a new object `HttpPostedFileBase` that get the info needed from your `MyCustomClass` object.

Answer (score 1):

If your class is serializable, then you can use a [BinaryFormatter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2). Following method can help:

```
public byte[] ConvertObjectToByteArray(object source)
{
    var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        formatter.Serialize(memoryStream, source);                
        return memoryStream.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Source: [convert a class to byte array + C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2689212/convert-a-class-to-byte-array-c-sharp)

Then you can use it as per the link:

```
// code will look like below:
MyCustomClass abc = new MyCustomClass();
var byteArray = ConvertObjectToByteArray(abc);
HttpPostedFileBase objFile = (HttpPostedFileBase)new MemoryPostedFile(byteArray);
```